# API choice: `inversePredict(mod,Xnew)` vs `predict(mod,Xnew;inv=true)`?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

For a ML library, which would be the arguments in favour to use a new specific function name for the inverse prediction for a model (e.g. a zero-mean/unit variance scaler), something like `inversePrediction(mod,Xnew)`, and which arguments would be in favour to just use a keyword argument to the already employed `predict` function, something like `predict(mod,Xnew;inv=true)` ?

Some context:

- I use only `predict(mod)` (and eventually `predict(mod,Xnew)` for models that generalise to new data) for unsupervised models and so-called transformers without distinguishing between them
- I use camel case
- MLJ and scikit-learn use `inverse_transform`
- I care more to user-friendly than performance

Comment: Is this inverse prediction an actual inverse? If so, I'd suggest sticking to some interface, like [InverseFunctions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/InverseFunctions.jl).